# Img map com mouseover

Tags: html, html5, imagem, maps

Esse é o código que possuo atualmente:

```
<img src="images/2.jpg" style="height:973px" border="0"  
onmouseover="this.src='images/1.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/2.jpg'" 
usemap="#image-map" >

<map name="image-map">
<area alt="CMPC Melhoramentos" title="CMPC Melhoramentos" href="../Cliente SP/production/iindex.php" coords="752,655,546,415" shape="rect">
<area alt="Indaial Papel" title="Indaial Papel" href="../IPEL/production/iindex.php" coords="1576,648,1308,413" shape="rect">
```

O map está estabelecido para a imagem `1.jpg`, que aparece ao passar o mouse. Contudo, quando passo o mouse precisamente em cima do retângulo estabelecido no map (para clicar) ele volta para a imagem inicial, a `2.jpg`, como se eu tivesse tirado o mouse. Como posso fazer para que isso não aconteça?

Comment: Renata edite sua pergunta e inclua também o seu CSS referente ao problema.

Comment: Na verdade não estou usando CSS neste caso, apenas esse código html.

Comment: Ficou mais claro agora. O que acontece é que quando vc faz o hover no mapa a imagem perde o :hover e volta para a imagem 2

Comment: Entendi... Existe alguma forma disso não acontecer?

Comment: Não entendi. A imagem 2 é a inicial. No ao passar o mouse vai pra imagem 1, ao tirar o mouse tb vai pra imagem 1

Comment: Veja: `onmouseover="this.src='images/1.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/1.jpg'" `... é tudo imagem 1

Comment: Acredito que sim, eu não entendo muito de JS então não vou saber te responder com precisão. Mas outra forma de fazer seria trocar a imagem1/2 no :hover pelo CSS, assim não precisaria do onmouseover do JS

Comment: Já alterei o código, no onmouseout era a imagem 2 mesmo.

Comment: Hugo, tentei alguns códigos no CSS mas não tive sucesso, não entendo muito de CSS então posso ter errado em algo. Se tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no seu `<map>` um `onmouseover` alterando para a mesma imagem do `onmouseover` da tag `<img>`:

```
<map name="image-map" onmouseover="document.querySelector('[usemap=\'#image-map\']').src='images/1.jpg'">
```

Não esqueça de fechar a tag `<map>`:

```
<map ....>
  ....
</map> ← fechar a tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de como vc pode fazer sem precisar de JS apenas com CSS. No caso são duas imagens, uma por cima da outra, mas quando vc possa o mouse na div a imagem que está por cima some e vc pode usar o map da imagem que está por baixo. Au tirar o mouse da imagem a outra imagem volta a aparecer por cima.

Veja o exemplo:

Passo o mouse sobre os planetas.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
div img {
    position: absolute;
}
div:hover img+img {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div >
    <img src ="https://www.w3schools.com/js/planets.gif" width ="145" height ="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" /> 
    <img src ="https://placecage.com/100/100" width ="145" height ="126" alt="" /> 

    <map name="planetmap">
    <area shape ="rect" coords ="0,0,82,126" href ="sun.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Sun" />
    
    <area shape ="circle" coords ="90,58,3" href ="mercur.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Mercury" />
    
    <area shape ="circle" coords ="124,58,8" href ="venus.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Venus" />
    </map>
</div>
```